# IP Spoofing for peer to peer connections over Cellular ISP

Tags: p2p, nat, spoofing, hole-punching

For Voip purpose, I'm looking to ways to create a peer to peer connection.

I already use a STUN-like server in order to connect 2 peers together. It works great for most NAT, but as expected, this technique does not work with symmetric NAT and random port affectation.

Most of Cellular network uses unfortunately symmetric NAT (even if they allow VOIP).

So I was wondering, would it work if each client sends an UDP packet to my rendez-vous server, in order to exchange each information (ip - port) with each others.
Then does a "ip-spoofing" technique from each client, making think the other Peer's NAT that the data is coming from my own rendez-vous server's ip. (Since the port as been opened on each Nat with the outgoing data)

It would let me avoid to create a proxy server that only use bandwidth for realying data from one peer to another.

Comment: I am very interesting in experimenting with this. Your post is a few years old, did you get anywhere or find any info? I see a few questions about this around the internet but no discussion or answers.

Comment: unfortunately it was a dead end since the Carrier NAT will never let through the data packet with another origin ip that is not the same as the device which sent it. This method works however with NAT at minimal security settings.

Comment: This is all about finding an ISP that doesn't check for spoofed IP packets. It exists, more because this has not been a security consideration for the ISP than as a real commercial offer.